# Should I sanitize the input for android

Tags: android, security

The user will type a text and then a button will have that text as value.Can the user do XSS injection? Should I sanitize the input? If yes how?

This is a little bit what would happen: http://jsfiddle.net/5q895/

```
<input type="text" id="asd" />
<input type="submit" id="zxc" onclick="qwe()" />
<script>
function qwe()
{
    document.getElementById("zxc").value=document.getElementById("asd").value;
}
</script>
```

(It is for android, I used JS to illustrate)

Comment: Do you mean like using malformed input text to create unwanted XML/UI elements?

Comment: @Pork Maybe? I don't know what could the user do. That's what I'm asking. If he would be able to "create unwanted elements", of course I should sanitize it, but could he?

Comment: what has that to do with android?

Comment: @Ridcully Look, I want to do an android app. And on this app, there is a textbox (or EditText) and when you click a button, there is another button which will get its value from the textbox. So I want to know if it's a security hole or no...

Comment: I understand that, but why do you post javascript code? Android is progammed in Java, so that'S a big difference. E.g. as some already pointed out malice text entered could alter your html-page via Javacsript, but that's not true for Android - even if someone would enter Java code, as Java is a compiled language while javascript is interpreted.

Comment: I posted this JS to "simulate" what would be on android. Anyway, you answered my question by saying "that's not true for Android". If you want, post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Okay, I posted it as an answer - slightly rewritten. Glad our little discussion did help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilest with HTML and JavaScript, malice text entered could alter your html-page via Javacsript, that's not true for Android. Android apps are programmed in Java, a compiled language in opposition to JavaScript which is interepreted. So even if someone would enter Java code just that code would appear as the Button's label but it cannot be executed.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your essential question regarding risks of not sanitizing user input if that input will then be used as the text for a Button.

The short answer is that there are no risks beyond length which might have the button popping out of it's expected layout due to length.

Answer (score 0):

You should always sanitize user input. For two main reasons.

**One**

Think of your users like that thought experiment where you put a bunch of monkeys in a room with typewriters, eventually, given enough time one of them will write something that Shakespeare wrote. A little bit in the same way, eventually on of your users might (unintentionally) input something that will mess up your system, even if it is only the submit button.

**Two**

People exist who'll actively try to mess with your system.

These two together create the simply rule, `always sanitize input`, your system should never expect to get input from an external source in an expected format. It should always pass by some sort of filter to be validated.

When it comes to your question how, well we have way to little information about your system to give any reasonable doubt. However don't expect any clientside validation of the input to be enough, because it isn't. You must validate data on the server as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Btw I'm doing an android app (no server or client here).

Comment: But the code example is html and javascript, on the Android platform you use xml to declare the layout and Java for the logic (and the GUI) if you want. There are no worries for `xss` if your app isn't doing any network communication.